# how can i use the wait_for command to look out for two different reactions in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I've got a bot which asks users if they are sure they entered the right information, showing them what they entered. I would like them to react with thumbs up for correct, and thumbs down for incorrect, but I can't seem to get the code to look out for both at once. Here's what I have... does anyone know how to do it?

```
def isUser(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author and (str(reaction.emoji) == '' or str(reaction.emoji) == '')
    
try:
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60, check=isUser)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await msg.edit(embed=embedEnd)
else:
    for i in msg.reactions:
        if i.emoji == '':
            if i.count > 1:
                await msg.edit(embed=embedFin)
        elif i.emoji == '':
            if i.count > 1:
                await msg.edit(embed=embedEnd)
```

`msg` is my bot's message.

`embedFin` is the embed i want to show when they react with .

`embedEnd` is the embes i want to show when they react with .

`bot` is commands.Bot().

let me know if you need more info! thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def isUser(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author and (str(reaction.emoji) == '' or str(reaction.emoji) == '')
    
try:
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60, check=isUser)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await msg.edit(embed=embedEnd)
else:
    if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        await msg.edit(embed=embedFin)
    else:
        await msg.edit(embed=embedEnd)
```

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb. Thank you. Lol.